# Get Response From iOS SDK ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, delegates

Quite new in creating the SDKs in iOS. Can anybody help me on the following scenario.

1. I have an SDK which has 3 view controllers, opened one by one in a seperate NavigationController. Screen A, Screen B and Screen C.
2. From Client application in which I am merging my SDK. I would have a button which would present my SDK Controllers enclosed within a UInavigationController. (I ll initialize Screen A Controller and then present that enclosed in a uinavigationcontroller as a rootviewcontroller)
3. Since First Controller in the navigation controller will be Screen A, it will have two buttons. One to close the window and other to goto the next screen (Screen B).
4. If User presses the close button I need to send the response to the client application that close button has been pressed. and if user presses the NEXT Screen button then Screen B will appear now on Screen B we have 3 buttons, to go Back, close screen and goto next screen. If user presses Close button on screen B then i would like to dismiss the presentedcontroller and again intimate the client app that the SDK controller window has been closed. Same is the case with 3rd screen.

I have one option that i can embedd Delegates in each controller etc. but I need some more professional and good ideas to implement this thing for my SDK. Please guide me ideas and best ways to do it. My language is OBJECTIVE-C.

Thanks

Comment: so finally you want that if screen is closed from any where the app must send a message to another app ?

Comment: yes and I dont want to write delegates in each and every controller as well

Comment: then what else you do after screen close ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking alot. I have come up with the following idea and when I implemented it, it was working like a charm. Just sharing if anybody also get into this situation.

1. Create a seperate Protocol Class file(.h file only) in your SDK. Name it whatever you want to name your Delegate. (Also make the class public in your SDK)
2. Declare required or optional methods in that header file.
3. Create id delagete instance in each controller. e.g In Controller A, B and C all will have that instance.
4. When user is trying to integrate the SDK in his application and tries to load Controller A from his client app, then also ask user to set its delegate to self and implement the required methods in his client app view controller.
5. In SDK when you are moving from Controller A to B and B to C and onwards just keep on passing the self.delegate to next controllers. (This will not create seperate instances, rather it is just pointing one delegate to all other controllers - So No Memory or performance issue occurs as well)
6. Now when you try to call [self.delegate yourMethodName:@"abc"] from any of the controllers A,B or C etc with different values then it will only be pointing to the mainController where the delegate was set as self.

This is how you can acheive it and you dont need to create different delegates/protocols in different controllers. You can just pass an extra parameter to the delegate method which can denote from which controller this delegate has return.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If delegate in each controller is not good enough for you, you can use only one transition delegate and check the incoming and outgoing view controllers.

Or if you use storyboard, you won't need delegate at all, just do the client app related calls in your segue functions.

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain a bit of your answer for one transition delegate. I am not using storyboard. Thanks